# Order of the Normalizer of a Sylow $p$-subgroup in $S_{p}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, sylow-theory

Question: Let $p$ be a prime and $P \leq S_{p}$ with $|P| = p$. Prove that $|N_{S_{p}}(P)| = p(p-1)$.

I have already solved this problem, but I have come across a proof that is much more elegant than my own. However, I'm not really convinced by it.

The proof is as follows. Any permutation $\sigma$ that normalizes $P$ should send $1$ to one of $\{1, \dots , p\}$ and $2 \mapsto \{1, \dots , p\} \setminus \{\sigma(1)\}$. The conclusion is that these $p(p-1)$ choices determine the permutation completely, but I do not see why this is necessarily the case.

Comment: Well it's true, but requires justification. Suppose that $P = \langle g \rangle$ with $g= (1,2,3,\ldots,p) $, and suppose there are two permutations $x,y \in N(P)$ with $x(1)=y(1)$, $x(2)=y(2)$. So $z:=x^{-1}y$ fixes $1$ and $2$, and we need to show that $z=1$. Since $zgz^{-1}$ is a power of $g$ and maps $1$ to $2$, we gave $zg=gz$, and then it's not hard to show that $z(i)=i$ for all $i$, so $z=1$.